# Is there pandas aggregate function that combines features of 'any' and 'unique'?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a large dataset with similar data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {'A': ['one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'one', 'three'],
...      'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', np.nan]})          
>>> df
       A    B
0    one    a
1    two    b
2    two    c
3    one    a
4    one    a
5  three  NaN
```

There are two aggregation functions 'any' and 'unique':

```
>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].any()
A
one       True
three    False
two       True
Name: B, dtype: bool

>>> df.groupby('A')['B'].unique()
A
one         [a]
three     [nan]
two      [b, c]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

but I want to get the folowing result (or something close to it):

```
A
one           a
three     False
two        True
```

I can do it with some complex code, but it is better for me to find appropriate function in python packages or the easiest way to solve problem. I'd be grateful if you could help me with that.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your expected output, please?

Comment: I need to get the value if this value is the only not-null value in the group. Also I need some flags for categories where there are no not-null values or count of not-null values more than one.

Comment: Is it possible to have something like [d, nan]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) for first column and unique values with remove possible missing values for another columns:

```
df1 = df.groupby('A').agg(count=('B','nunique'), 
                          uniq_without_NaNs = ('B', lambda x: x.dropna().unique()))
print (df1)
       count uniq_without_NaNs
A                             
one        1               [a]
three      0                []
two        2            [b, c]
```

Then create mask if greater column `count` by `1` and replace values by `uniq_without_NaNs` if equal `count` with `1`:

```
out = df1['count'].gt(1).mask(df1['count'].eq(1), df1['uniq_without_NaNs'].str[0])
print (out)
A
one          a
three    False
two       True
Name: count, dtype: object
```

Comment: It looks like something that works correctly, thanks! Can you explain, please, how did you get the value out of list in the first row? Is it the feature of interpreter? I've got the list of one value instead.

Comment: @Anna - What is `print (df1.to_dict())` with your data?

Comment: {'count': {'one': 1, 'three': 0, 'two': 2}, 'uniq_without_NaNs': {'one': array(['a'], dtype=object), 'three': array([], dtype=object), 'two': array(['b', 'c'], dtype=object)}}

Comment: @Anna - Now should working well.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> g = df.groupby("A")["B"].agg
>>> nun = g("nunique")
>>> pd.Series(np.select([nun > 1, nun == 1],
                        [True, g("unique").str[0]],
                        default=False),
              index=nun.index)

A
one          a
three    False
two       True
dtype: object
```

- get a hold on the group aggreagator
- count number of uniques

  - if > 1, i.e., more than 1 uniques, put True
  - if == 1, i.e., only 1 unique, put that unique value
  - else, i.e., no uniques (full NaNs), put False

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really works and logic is ideal. I have never used np.select, will research it. Maybe someone will find more easy and elegant way

Comment: np. np.select is vectorized if-elif-elif-...-else. First conditions are passed, second the choices corresponding to them, and lastly the fallback (default, else) value.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `groupby` with `agg` and use boolean mask to choose the correct output:

```
# Your code
agg = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['any', 'unique'])

# Boolean mask to choose between 'any' and 'unique' column
m = agg['unique'].str.len().eq(1) & agg['unique'].str[0].notna()

# Final output
out = agg['any'].mask(m, other=agg['unique'].str[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> out
A
one          a
three    False
two       True

>>> agg
         any  unique
A                   
one     True     [a]
three  False   [nan]
two     True  [b, c]

>>> m
A
one       True  # choose 'unique' column
three    False  # choose 'any' column
two      False  # choose 'any' column
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will use something like that and add nunique column to get mask. First time using mask in that way, good intro, will research it too

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x.notna().any())
new_df = new_df .reset_index()
new_df .columns = ['A', 'B']
```

this will give you:

```
       A      B
0    one   True
1  three  False
2    two   True
```

now if we want to find the values we can do:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x[x.notna()].unique()[0] if x.notna().any() else np.nan)
```

which gives:

```
A
one        a
three    NaN
two        b
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
series = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique()))
```

will give the next result:

```
one        a
three    Nan
two   [b, c]
```

where simple value can be identified by the type:

```
series[series.apply(type) == str]
```

Think it is easy enough to use often, but probably it is not the optimal solution.